# Solve : $x^4 + 6x^3 -3x^2 + 2 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

$x^4 + 6x^3 -3x^2 + 2 = 0$

To find the zeros, I tried this by Ferrari's method but got stuck where a value of 'lambda' has to be obtained.

Comment: If it was by any chance $x^4+6x^3+3x^2+2=0$, then $x=-1$ is a nice root.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't pretty!

See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%20%2b%206x%5E3%20-3x%5E2%20%2b%202%20=%200), e.g.:

Real roots:

[image]

[image]

---

The two complex roots are just as "messy."

Comment: nice opportunity for a $\LaTeX$ work-out...

Comment: @draks Only if I get really bored! ;-)

Comment: Wow,the roots are beautiful...

Comment: Nice use of Wolfram Alpha software+1. I discovered this software in this site and in my country the popular software Maple:-)